# Excluding field names from list based on Custom Metadata

Tags: apex

I'm calling `getCustomSettingObjectsFields` method in another static method where I have a list need to remove the `excludedfeilds` set values from `allCampaignFieldList`

PFB Code:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> schemaFieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.fields.getMap();//Get the schema field map to get all the fields

allCampaignFieldList.addAll(schemaFieldMap.keySet());

public static void getCustomSettingObjectsFields(){
        system.debug('getCustomSettingObjectsFields');
        Set<String> excludedfeilds =new Set<String>();
        for(CM_Campaign_Clone_Data_Field__mdt dmso:[SELECT DeveloperName from CM_Campaign_Clone_Data_Field__mdt ]){
            system.debug('excludedSObjects'+dmso.DeveloperName);
            excludedfeilds.add(dmso.DeveloperName);
        }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
public static void getCustomSettingObjectsFields(){
    system.debug('getCustomSettingObjectsFields');
    Set<String> excludedfeilds = new Set<String>();
    for(CM_Campaign_Clone_Data_Field__mdt dmso :[SELECT DeveloperName from CM_Campaign_Clone_Data_Field__mdt ]){
        system.debug('excludedSObjects'+dmso.DeveloperName);
        excludedfeilds.add(dmso.DeveloperName);

        //Check if developeName exists in list
        for(Integer i=0; i<allCampaignFieldList.size(); i++){
            if(allCampaignFieldList.contains(dmso.DeveloperName)){
                allCampaignFieldList.remove(i); //Removes the excludedfeilds
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You add case sensitive checks by either of these methods:

```
if(allCampaignFieldList[i].equalsIgnoreCase(dmso.DeveloperName))

if(allCampaignFieldList[i] == dmso.DeveloperName.toLowerCase())

if(allCampaignFieldList[i].equals(dmso.DeveloperName.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a loop for this at all, or write your own logic: you just need the [`Set` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#!).

Let's say you have a `List<String> allCampaignFieldList` and you want to remove from it all the fields returned by `getCustomSettingObjectsFields()`, which returns a `Set<String>`.

Start by converting `allCampaignFieldList` to a `Set<String>`:

```
Set<String> allCampaignFieldSet = new Set<String>(allCampaignFieldList);
```

Then, you can remove all entries in the `Set` returned by your method in a single call:

```
allCampaignFieldSet.removeAll(getCustomSettingObjectsFields());
```

Note that `Set` membership testing is case-sensitive. If you're concerned about case-sensitivity, simply convert all Strings to lowercase before you add them to the two Sets in the first place.

You can then convert your `allCampaignFieldSet` back to a list, if desired, or continue to use it as a Set.